# Managed metadata vs lookup for column

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-online, lookup-column, managed-metadata

I have a property content type. I'm wanting to add a property code column which will look up the codes from somewhere else on a SharePoint Online site, where it can easily be managed by end users.

I initially implemented this having a lookup column pointing to a custom list. The issue with this solution was:

1. No search function (Within other browsers apart from Internet Explorer)
2. Drop down menu so will become impractical when the property list becomes large.

As an alternative I set up a term set with the idea of using managed metadata. This seems like the perfect solution but the one issue that arises is adding additional terms. The property codes are going to be constantly added. The only way I've found to add additional terms to a term set is through the Term Store Management Tool, either manually or through a csv import. Both will be beyond the ability of the site users.

What are my options here? Are managed metadata term sets meant to have constantly changing data?

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Btw The Lookup drop down will change when you get 20 items. Then you can type in the field to find values

Comment: I did not realise. Thank you very much for pointing this out to me!

Comment: This functionality only seems to work within IE, which isn't very useful for the end users of my site.

Comment: As a side note, if its an option, you can develop a simple custom search page which can search any fields you specify. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allow specific users to add terms to the termset via the term picker control. There are two options: either you have to click the term icon on the right and than add term or you can directly write a new term in the text box.

Go to Central Administration and set the submission policy of the term set to open. Than add the users that should be able to add terms to the term group with the approriate rights. Than you can configure the taxonomy site column in your site or list.